# Azure SQL Server SSL certificate verification fails

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I am seeing some strange results with SSL certificate verification in relation to Azure SQL Server.

I have an application that is making a secure connection to SQL server.  When I run the application on my local PC, the certificate returned by the server returns the following alt DNS names:

`DNS:northcentralus1-a.control.database.windows.net, DNS:*.northcentralus1-a.control.database.windows.net, DNS:management.northcentralus1-a.control.database.windows.net, DNS:management.northcentralus.control.database.windows.net, DNS:admin.northcentralus1-a.control.database.windows.net, DNS:*.database.windows.net, DNS:*.secondary.database.windows.net, DNS:*.provisioning.database.windows.net`

This is what I would expect, and it matches the server I am trying to talk to under `*.database.windows.net`.

However, when I deploy that same application into Azure, the SQL Server seems to return a different certificate with the following alt DNS names:

`DNS:tr1.northcentralus1-a.worker.database.windows.net, DNS:*.tr1.northcentralus1-a.worker.database.windows.net`

These names do not match the server I am trying to talk to, so my client application rejects the connection due to it being an untrusted host.

There was a similar issue entered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227296/azure-sql-database-error-tls-handshake-failed-since-v12-upgrade), but the solution accepted was to just always trust the certificate without checking it.  My question is different in that I would like to verify the certificate, not blindly trust the certificate.

Here are the specific questions, summarized:

- Is Azure SQL Server providing an invalid certificate?
- Assuming it is providing an invalid certificate, can I configure Azure SQL Server to provide a valid certificate?
- Assuming it is providing an invalid certificate, is Azure SQL Server planning on correcting the behavior, or are we supposed to perpetually trust the certificate without checking?

Comment: That answer does not solve the root issue.  It just ignores the issue.

Comment: [sql-database-security-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview) is here quoted "you must specify parameters to encrypt the connection and not to trust the server certificate".  How do I do this successfully?